# c++ allocated memory in dllmain/ __attribute__ constructor

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been reading about what happens when you do some initialization for a shared library. The concept is all well and good, but I'm unclear as to how memory is allocated and the scope it has in the program.

Take for instance creating an integer in DLLMain (whether it's process_attach or thread_attach) on the stack or heap. Is that integer in the global scope of the program or would it be somewhere else? As in, if I new'd in an integer in DLLMain would it be accessible globally in the program, or just specially to main or perhaps some other weird case? If it is accessible in the global scope, does that mean that all threads can access that memory as well?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Removed the linux tag as a "dynamic loadable library" containing a function `DllMain` is a windows-only thing.

Comment: I was also asking about using __attribute__((constructor)) which as I understand is the linux equivalent....

Comment: I suggest split the question in two, one for windows, another for linux, since they operate somehow different, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Any thread that knows its address can access it. All threads have the same view of virtual memory. It doesn't matter what allocator it comes from because once it's mapped into virtual memory, all memory acts the same.